# Finding previously deleted code in RTC later?

Tags: version-control, rational-team-concert

Conventional wisdom says to delete code once you don't need it -- as opposed to leaving it in the codebase as a comment -- because you can always find it later in the repository.

Let's say I need a line of code from the past which I remember to contain a very memorable substring ("XYZ", for discussion's sake).

What are my options for finding the previously deleted code using the Visual Studio 2010 Rational Team Concert (3.x) client?  Can I search only the revisions of a single file (I might not know what file it was in)?  Can I search quickly/easily across many files (w/o pulling those files out of the repository)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure there is an easy way to get back the exact file with that missing string.

You can select show the history on a component of a Stream, in order to "Show the History files" for a given change set.

From there, you can do some "compare with Local File".

However, the Visual Studio integration might be less complete than the eclipse one, as [this thread shows](https://jazz.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=8558&view=previous&sid=43f179110e14f54b719049a643b2726b) (where the "Show History" shows only the history of Deliver's).

Even though the following article uses the Eclipse GUI, have also a look at "[Practicing source control archaeology with Rational Team Concert](https://jazz.net/library/article/447/)", which has other ideas for you to try.